# Outlook.com makes text clickable

Tags: hotmail, outlook.com

[image]

This is my send mail: [image]
When I manually type exact the same text it does not become clickable

When I send a mail from my template to my hotmail account my text become clickable/blue but there is no hyperlink is there anyway to fix this?

Note: This is not happening with any other mail client

Edit: Bug is in all browsers so its not a plug-in / add-on that makes this happen.

Comment: There's no way to tell what causes this until you show your template code and a source view of the sent message. Also verify that this isn't caused by a browser plugin/addon.

Comment: Tried to add usefull information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template was half copied from Word.
I manually typed over the full template and now I have no issue's.
I still have no idea what caused this bug.

EDIT: It was probably the bookmark which I copied from word that caused the bug